# Machine Learning with a list predictor

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have taken a data set and manipulated it in such a way that each data point is a list of numerical values, whose order is irrelevant, and an expected output, which is numerical (I'm doing regression, not classification). However, the lists may not be the same length, and the order of the values in the lists doesn't matter, so it doesn't make sense to just train a neural network with the k-th entry as the predictor x_k.

But I need to be able to predict the numerical output based on a list of input values. (For context, this list is a list of sound frequencies, so I should be able to predict the numerical value associated with the sound based on a list of its most intense frequencies)

I'm totally at a loss of what kind of learning algorithm will be useful here (although I'd prefer something related to neural networks) or where to go now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The learning algorithm depends a lot on your input characteristics and the output needed.  Please illustrate with examples and semantics.  Are the frequencies a finite set, that you could use 1-hot encoding?  What sort of similarities do you have to generalize and discriminate within the data?  How dense are the generality clusters?  What sorts of outliers do you have, and how should they get handled?